# Using Where cluase while loading data in Qlikview From Database

Tags: qlikview

Need help using Where cluase while loading data in Qlikview From Database

Following is the script that executes perfectly

```
    LET vCutOffDate  = MakeDate(2015,10,14);
    LOAD `CITY_NM`,
        `CST_NM`,
        `CST_TP`,
        `DATA_DATE`
    ;
    SQL SELECT `CITY_NM`,
        `CST_NM`,
        `CST_TP`,
        `DATA_DATE`
    FROM TEST.`ABC`
    ;
```

When I add "where" clause it shows weird behavior for Greater than(>),Less Than(<) And Equal to(=) operators,
Script Does not fetch any data for < and = operator whereas fetches all the data when I use > operator.

Below is the final script I am trying along with where clause

```
    LET vCutOffDate  = MakeDate(2015,10,14);
    LOAD `CITY_NM`,
        `CST_NM`,
        `CST_TP`,
        `DATA_DATE`
    ;
    SQL SELECT `CITY_NM`,
        `CST_NM`,
        `CST_TP`,
        `DATA_DATE`
    FROM TEST.`ABC`
    WHERE (`DATA_DATE`<'$(vCutOffDate)')
    ;
```

Following are the date values I see If I view DATA_DATE by Select_Fields option

```
    10/11/2015 0:00
    10/14/2015 0:00
    10/18/2015 0:00
    10/31/2015 0:00
```

Comment: what is the result when you run the query without using the variable? like: `WHERE (`DATA_DATE`<'10/11/2015')`? Also what is the variable result when running the query? You can check with the debug mode or trace it: `trace $(vCutOffDate)`

Comment: trace $(vCutOffDate)  shows variable value to be   14/10/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem lies in the date formatting. It depends on the database, which date format is needed, but this should work.

```
LET vCutOffDate  = TimeStamp(MakeDate(2015,10,14), 'YYYYMMDD');
LOAD `CITY_NM`,
    `CST_NM`,
    `CST_TP`,
    `DATA_DATE`
;
SQL SELECT `CITY_NM`,
    `CST_NM`,
    `CST_TP`,
    `DATA_DATE`
FROM TEST.`ABC`
WHERE (`DATA_DATE`<'$(vCutOffDate)')
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Adding TimeStamp() function worked